# Server-Based CRON Job

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-cron

We want to move a CRON job from being triggered in WordPress to a server-based job. Right now the code lives in the *functions.php* file in our WP theme, and we use the WPCrontrol plugin for scheduling. It runs fine, no problem there. The issue is the code has WooCommerce hooks in it. A server-based job has no idea what to do with `WC_Orders`, for example. How can we resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can resolve this with this way:

- Step 1: You create a PHP Page with URL you want in your theme like this (page-url-custom-cron.php) to call a Hook WooCommerce
- Step 2: You use server-based job Curl to the URL: http://yourdomain/url-custom-cron. And now the PHP code page will call WooCommerce hooks for you.

Hope this can help you done your job

Comment: I spoke too soon. I was able to get the job to run using cURL, but it still doesn't know what to do with the hooks.

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wc_get_orders()`

Comment: If your WooCommerce version is 2.2+ you must use $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );. But with the older version you must use $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );. hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

1. Created a file (run_cron.php) which called the job I needed to run via cURL and placed it in the child theme folder:
   cURL:

   ```
   <?php
     define('RUN_CRON_URI', 'https://path-to-file-to-be-executed/process_orders.php');

     $curl = curl_init();
     curl_setopt_array($curl, [
         CURLOPT_URL => RUN_CRON_URI,
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
         CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
         CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
     ]);

     $result = curl_exec($curl);

     if (curl_error($curl)) {
         throw new Exception(curl_error());
     } else {
         $httpStatusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         if ($httpStatusCode != 200) {
             throw new Exception('Submission failed with this status: ' . $httpStatusCode);
         } elseif (stripos($result, 'error') !== false) {
             throw new Exception('Error detected: ' . $result);
         }
     } ?>
   ```
2. Moved the job to be executed into the parent theme folder.
3. Added the following at the top of the executable file in opening and closing PHP tags:

   /**
      * @package OceanWP WordPress theme
      */

   require_once("../../../wp-load.php");

Rest of the code...